# HTTP PUT a PNG with Fetch API

Tags: javascript, base64, fetch-api

I have a Base64 encoded image called `imgBase64`.

How can I HTTP PUT this PNG from a browser using the Fetch API?

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'put',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'image/png'
    },
    body: atob(imgBase64) // <--------- what should I be doing here?
});
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. What exactly is the issue/error you are running into?

Comment: @CRice `await fetch` throws "DOMException: String contains an invalid character"

Comment: any example of imgBase64 or where does it come from? As the error are thrown by ``atob()``

Comment: A guess: atob will only decode regular base64, not the "url safe" version in which `+` and `/` are replaced with `-` and `_` respectively. Perhaps your encoded image is using that url safe version?

Comment: @CRice Correction: It seems `atob` is throwing the error!

Comment: @wuiyang data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAQ4CAYAAADo08FDAAAgAElEQVR4XuzZQREAAAgCQelf2h43awMWf+wcAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECCQElkghBAEC...

Comment: When you call `atob` on that string, you must remove the `data:image/png;base64,` prefix. Is this the issue?

Comment: @CRice I just checked the string and it seems to contain `+`s

Comment: @CRice Yes I think that's the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `imgBase64` is already encoded, you can add `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header and remove `atob` method:

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'put',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'image/png',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'base64'
    },
    body: imgBase64
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
let imageResponse = await fetch(imgBase64); 

const putResponse = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'put',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'image/png',
    },
    body: await imageResponse.blob()
});
```